# Protractor : What is the best way to manage dropped file from explorer?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, protractor, end-to-end

I try to test an angular application on which adding data can only be done by files drag and drop from OS explorer. I understand that files drag and drop can't be directly test by webdriver because explorer is not a part of browser.

Anyway, I need a way to adding some data to my app to test it. I thought of different approaches. 
The first one was to directly call my backend REST API to add the data. I tried this approache by following this blog post (http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/) and I can send data to the server. But many checks and transformation on the data are done by my front-end app on drop, before to send data to server, and with this approache I cant' use them. These checks and transformations are already tests in Unit Test, but it is a little bit frustrating to have to rewrite these in my test to manage my data files...

**So, I thought that it would be great if I can use my validation files directly by calling controller function which handle dropped files. With this approache, I skip only the drag and drop part but I test with e2e all process which are made after drop.** It would be really nice, but I can't figure out how to do this... I don't even know if it's possible to do something like that...

Any advice would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter if you drag'n'drop file, or just pass file directly? Validation should be same for both? You can actually upload files with protractor pretty easily:

```
var path = require('path');

var uploadFile = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
var jpgAbsolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../td/image.jpg');
uploadFile.sendKeys(jpgAbsolutePath);
```

Comment: Yes, except that we don't have any file input in our app :)

Comment: Well, you should be able to call that controller function with js: `browser.driver.executeScript('alert('some kind of controller call')');`

Comment: I didn't know this syntax. Thanks. Unfortunatly I can't test it because I'm not on this project anymore.